# can chug be used with food, like chugging down my lunch

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, terminology

Everywhere I've looked, it seems chugging down has to be followed by a drink. But can I use it with food as well? Like "I was doing something (say, walking) while chugging down my lunch". Is it okay? If not, what's a better way to say it?

Edit:
In the context I'm trying to use it, I don't want any pleasant connotations with it, or make it seem like the person is enjoying it or hungry even, or eating 'enthusiastically', as 'scarf' seems to suggest. In my context the person is doing it out of necessity, in a depressing/sad way. That's why 'chugging down' was the first solution that popped up--there's nothing necessarily pleasant about it, and one can eat in the same manner as he would chug down a drink (literally without chewing and finish it within the span of seconds). I'm also thinking about Yosef's comment under my question about what makes something okay and not okay, especially when it's a slang. Any thoughts on this?

To further clarify:

1. Chugging down doesn't necessary imply enthusiasm or appetite (in my opinion).
2. I do want the intensity / speed / mechanics / imagery of 'chugging down' to be there -- it's not merely the depressing aspect of it I'm trying to get at.

Comment: It's slang, so it's up to you. People say they inhaled their food, so that's metaphorical as well. Wolfed it down. Exaggeration is normal.

Comment: 'Chugging down' hasn't reached the UK as far as I know, though we do say 'chucking down' for a drink. Gulping, gulping down and gobbling can be used for food, but they're not slang.

Comment: Only if you put it through a blender first.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up *chug* in a good dictionary?

Comment: Chugging is usually reserved for drink and most often alcoholic drink at that.

Comment: Add the links to one or more dictionary references and I'll cast my reopen vote. It's clear that you know the meaning but some users are pretty zealous about proof of  "research" and nowadays only 3 votes are needed to close a question...

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you mean by "chug". With a drink it would mean to [drink all at once without pausing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chug), but that doesn't make sense with food (you can't just open your mouth and pour a burger and fries in) or in the context that you're doing something else at the same time as chugging your food (chugging a drink requires all your attention). Are you meaning "eat", "eat carelessly", "eat messily", "eat fast", "eat with no regard for taste", or some other connotation of chug?

Comment: @StuartF Edited my question.

Comment: You asked for the equivalent of "chug" without realizing how the word was used (drinking with speed) and in what context but we couldn't have known this. If you wanted an expression to say someone eating their food without appetite or enthusiasm, mechanically as if an automaton you should ask a new question.

Comment: Chugging down doesn't necessary imply enthusiasm or appetite (in my opinion) @Mari-LouA

Comment: And I do want the intensity / speed / mechanics / imagery of 'chugging down' to be there. It's not merely the depressing aspect of it I'm trying to get at. @Mari-LouA If that makes sense?

Comment: Eat something quickly in a depressing/sad way IMO cannot be said in one word.

Comment: So you want something along the lines of “he mechanically crammed his mouth full of food and swallowed.”

Answer (score 6):

No, the word chug is not supposed to be used with food, as in "*chugging* down my lunch"

The word "chug" applies only to beverages and other liquids

- Sarah dared Hilary to **chug** down a **beer** (YES)
- I was **chugging** down a glass of **lemonade** when the doorbell rang (YES)
- Harry **chugged** down a **sandwich** (NO. Sandwiches are not liquids)
- Bob **chugged** down a glass full of **bleach** (grammatically correct, but inadvisable)

---

If you want to talk about solid food, then you could say:

- I **snarfed** down my lunch
- I **gobbled** down my lunch in a hurry.
- I **wolfed** down my lunch.
- I ate my lunch **quickly**
- I ate my lunch **hastily**

  - only aristocrats, and people born 300 years ago use the word "**hastily**," so I do not recommend it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have lived in the United States for almost 30 years. I have never heard someone use to word "*chug*" for meals or solid foods.

Comment: Great. Then please edit your answer and include that information in your answer. These are things which learners can never be 100% certain.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The verb for food is ***wolf***.  *He wolfed down a hotdog and ran out the door.*

Comment: @Jim In fact, I upvoted as soon as it was suggested in the answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Oops I didn’t see the update with that in it.

Comment: _scarf_ is a word for both eating and drinking voraciously.

Comment: In the context I'm trying to use it, I don't want any pleasant connotations with it, or make it seem like the person is enjoying it or hungry even, or eating 'enthusiastically', as 'scarf' seems to suggest. In my context the person is doing it out of necessity, in a depressing/sad way. That's why 'chugging down' was the first solution that popped up--there's nothing necessarily pleasant about it, and one can eat in the same manner as he would chug down a drink. I'm also thinking about Yosef's comment under my question about what makes something okay and not okay, especially when it's a slang.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my edit. I wonder it it changes things. And @Mari-LouA as well.

Comment: Yes, your edit does change things quite a bit. It's almost invalidated Samuel's answer. If Samuel Muldoon wants to edit his answer to reflect the clarification, he's most welcome to.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought this current answer still answers the edited OPs question well. There are many parallel words of drink:chug::food:... that fit the more explicit criteria and wolf/snarf/gobble still fit for me.

Comment: @Mitch well.... the 2nd clarification helps to anchor the Q.

Comment: I also don’t agree with the OP that *chug* has a connotation of “for necessity and unpleasantness without enjoyment”

Comment: I feel like chug is neutral in this department, that it doesn't imply enjoyment and appetite, is what I was trying to say. @Jim

Comment: So maybe “he quickly choked down a sandwich and ran out the door”

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer following your edit that the term should not connote gustatory pleasure:

> You [**ploughed/plowed**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/plough-through-sth) through your meal.

To **plough/plow** through something is to complete a task ([with finishing a meal being a typical example](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/plough-through)) with difficulty or great effort; in this case, to doggedly or determinedly consume food with steady progress in an analogous way to chugging a liquid.